# remove an element in an array of Hash in rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Here is my rspec code:-

```
 it "should match with valid address" do
    get :index, Devise.token_authentication_key => @user.authentication_token, business_id: @business2.id
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    expect(response.body).to eq([@location].to_json(LocationFinder::API_PARAMS.merge(:root => false)))
  end
```

expected:

```
 "[
   {
   \"address\":\"1120 Milky Way\",
   \"business_id\":1,
   \"city\":\"Cupertino\",
   \"latitude\":\"2.4\",
   \"longitude\":\"2.9\",
   \"name\":\"Joe's Diner\"
   }
  ]"
```

got:

```
 "[
   {
   \"address\":\"1120 Milky Way\",
   \"business_id\":1,
   \"city\":\"Cupertino\",
   \"latitude\":\"2.4\",
   \"longitude\":\"2.9\",
   \"name\":\"Joe's Diner\",
   \"distance\":712.7948793
   }
  ]"
```

how can i remove a "distance" field into this array that contain Hash value. so my test will success.

Comment: format the code properly

Comment: Is it a hash, or a Json string?

Comment: this output is got from rspec and this may be a json output

Answer (score 3):

You can delete a `key` from that hash with the `delete` method, For instance:

```
require 'json'
a = "[
   {
   \"address\":\"1120 Milky Way\",
   \"business_id\":1,
   \"city\":\"Cupertino\",
   \"latitude\":\"2.4\",
   \"longitude\":\"2.9\",
   \"name\":\"Joe's Diner\",
   \"distance\":712.7948793
   }
  ]"

  a = JSON.parse(a)
  a[0].delete "distance"
  p a

  #output:

  # [{"address"=>"1120 Milky Way", "business_id"=>1, "city"=>"Cupertino", "latitude"=>"2.4", "longitude"=>"2.9", "name"=>"Joe's Diner"}]
```

Comment: @GauravSharma You'll have to update the question with the relevant rspec code that it is not working.

Comment: Don't use `JSON.load` unless you explicitly need to deserialize an object created using `JSON.dump` (which you should basically never do). Instead, you should use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.generate`. The `load`/`dump` mechanism is susceptible to exactly the same serious security issues that YAML has (and which causes rather large grief among Rails people)

Comment: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass, this error is not resolved by rspec

Comment: That means (in the context of the code I posted here), that position 0 (`a[0]`) doesn't contain a hash. Reviewing the updated code, shouldn't you call this: `@location.delete "distance"` before the `.to_json` call? How are you currently calling the code I posted here?

Comment: result = expect(response.body).to_json,  @a = JSON.parse(@result), 
        @ans = @a[12].delete "distance"

Comment: In that case, the error means there's no position `12` in the `@a` array. Try logging the array to find the proper array element.

Comment: i also try from 0 to 12 but same error , i think in @a cannot contain json data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27331/discussion-between-fmendez-and-gaurav-sharma)